# Will trigger affect replication process between two databases

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a scenario where two `databases A &` B are synching. i have another `database C` which is not synching & i want to `insert/update` few columns from a table from `Database A` to `Database C` trough trigger.(It means when i will update some records in `Database A` table that trigger will update the same record to `Database C` table also). Will this trigger affect the replication process?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is No! trigger will not affect the replication process but changes those are applied to `Database A` will be reflected in `Database B` as well because of replication.